# Unable to find bluecove jar while executing the project as a .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, noclassdeffounderror, bluecove

My Java Swing application works fine when I run it from eclipse. But when I try to run it as a jar file, it fails to recognise my referenced libraries (bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) and gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/bluetooth/UUID

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.bluetooth.UUID
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Is there something wrong in the way I am creating the jar file or is there some issue with the bluecove jar itself?

Comment: Put it in classpath.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893337/putting-a-jar-file-in-classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to export it to a jar and then manually adding the main class in manifest.MD and the jars it was using. All I had to do was export it to an 'executable' jar and check the extract all jars option while exporting :)

Answer (score 1):

this is simple

right click on project-->Build Path-->Configure build path-->Order and Export

and check wheather  bluecove library is marked if not check mark